# How to solve for exponents in an infinite product?

Tags: equation-solving

Say I have a power series, $f(x,y) \in 1 + x\mathbb{Z}[[x,y]]$

Then it admits a unique expansion

$$f(x,y) = \prod_{i=1}^\infty \prod_{j=0}^\infty (1 - x^i y^j)^{n_{i,j}}$$

for some integers, $i, j$.

More to the point, the $n_{i,j}$ for $i \le N$ and $j \le M$ 
are determined uniquely by

$$f(x,y) = 1 + \sum_{i=1}^N \sum_{j=0}^M f_{i,j} x^i y^j = \prod_{i=1}^N \prod_{j=0}^M (1 - x^i y^j)^{n_{i,j}} + O(x^{N+1}, y^{M+1})$$

> How do I solve for the $n_{i,j}$ given the $f_{i,j}$?

In principle there is some matrix with integer coefficients that needs to be inverted, but do I have to first generate that matrix (how?) and invert it, or can I just write something like the above in Mathematica and say ``solve'' ?

Comment: (1) Evaluate at n*(m+1) points (x,y). (2) Take logs both sides. This gives a set of linear equations in the `n[i,j]`.

Answer (score 1):

The following code computes $n_{i,j}$ recursively in terms of $f_{i,j}$ and of $n_{a,b}$ for $a<i$ and $b≤j$.  The idea is that the exponent of $(1-x^iy^j)$ is the $x^iy^j$ term in the product $\prod_{a<i,b≤j}(1-x^ay^b)^{n_{a,b}}$, minus $f_{i,j}$.

```
ClearAll[n, f];

n[f_][i_Integer?Positive, j_Integer?NonNegative] :=
  n[f][i, j] = 
   SeriesCoefficient[
     Product[(1 - x^a y^b)^n[f][a, b], {a, i - 1}, {b, 0, j}],
     {x, 0, i}, {y, 0, j}] - f[i, j];

(*Let's do an example: f=1+x+x*y+x*y^5.*)
f[0, 0] := 1;
f[1, 0] := 1;
f[1, 1] := 1;
f[1, 5] := 1;
f[i_Integer?NonNegative, j_Integer?NonNegative] := 0;

(*Two presentations of the results*)
Table[n[f][i, j], {i, 4}, {j, 0, 30}]
Product[(1 - x^a y^b)^n[f][a, b], {a, 4}, {b, 0, 10}]

(*Check the result is correct.*)
Series[
 Product[(1 - x^a y^b)^n[f][a, b], {a, 4}, {b, 0, 10}],
 {x, 0, 4}, {y, 0, 10}]
```